# Filtering with tags in Shopify with Collections of Collections

Tags: tags, shopify, liquid

In Shopify, I'd like to have tags available on a level where there are no products so I can use tag filtering.

For example, on a website selling jewelry, here's the hierarchy:

```
level 0: homepage (rings, earrings, pendants, or the-john-smith-collection)

level 1: grid of top level collection (earrings, for example)

level 2: grid of sub-collection (model-123) of earrings 

level 3: grid of all earrings of model-123

level 4: product page for earring-xyz of model-123
```

I understand that I'm able to filter by tags on level 3 without a problem because I'm looking at bunch of products in a category.

My question is - is there ANY way to have access to all of the tags for all of the products in every model (sub-collection) on level 2. I'd have a collection with a bunch of sub-collections, but no actual products, but I want to be able to filter by all of the tags of the products located in those sub-collections, so I'm able to do the following:

```
From the homepage, select the "rings" collection

See the rings category - a grid of 20 different sub-collections

Have a side filter menu, from which I'm able to click "see only rings tagged with "amethyst"

Be taken to a grid of all products matching those tags
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this question, but this is possible in Shopify.

I recently came across one of Shopify's free themes that has it built in, [New Standard](https://themes.shopify.com/themes/new-standard/styles/white/preview), and it can be found in the Customize panel under the Collection page, "Show browse by tag".

But, I also found [this article](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/filter-a-collection-using-product-tags) on Shopify that shows you how to program in your own dropdown that can browse by tag. This code only works *after* a collection has been chosen.

```js
<script>
  /* Product Tag Filters - Good for any number of filters on any type of collection pages */
  /* Brought to you by Caroline Schnapp */
  var collFilters = jQuery('.coll-filter');
  collFilters.change(function() {
    var newTags = [];
    collFilters.each(function() { 
      if (jQuery(this).val()) {
        newTags.push(jQuery(this).val());
      }
    });
    if (newTags.length) {
      var query = newTags.join('+');
      window.location.href = jQuery('{{ 'tag' | link_to_tag: 'tag' }}').attr('href').replace('tag', query);
    } 
    else {
      {% if collection.handle %}
      window.location.href = '/collections/{{ collection.handle }}';
      {% elsif collection.products.first.type == collection.title %}
      window.location.href = '{{ collection.title | url_for_type }}';
      {% elsif collection.products.first.vendor == collection.title %}
      window.location.href = '{{ collection.title | url_for_vendor }}';
      {% endif %}
    }
  });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="clearfix filter">
  <p>Browse by tag:</p>
  <select class="coll-filter">
    <option value="">All</option>
    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
    {% if current_tags contains tag %}
    <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tag }}</option>
    {% else %}
    <option value="{{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

Good luck and I hope this works for you!